# VBA in Excel 2010: Scripting.Dictionary return value of a function won't pass as parameter to a wrapping function call

Tags: excel, function, vba, parameters, return-value

Have been banging my head off the table for a couple of hours over this and already searched the chuff our of the interweb, so apologies if I've missed an obvious solution...

I have 2 functions:

```
Public Function DictFromRanges(rKeys As Range, rValues As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Debug.Assert (rKeys.Columns.Count = rValues.Columns.Count)

    Dim rRetDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set rRetDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' loop through ranges adding values from rValues with keys from rKeys
    Dim iKey As Integer
    For iKey = 1 To rKeys.Columns.Count
        rRetDict(rKeys.Columns(iKey).Value) = rValues.Columns(iKey).Value
    Next iKey

    ' set return value
    Set DictFromRanges = rRetDict

End Function

Public Function MinTurnsToKill(dictAttack As Scripting.Dictionary, iHealth As Integer) As Integer

   MinTurnsToKill = iHealth

End Function
```

If I do the following in a cell of the spreadsheet:

```
=MinTurnsToKill(DictFromRanges(F2:L2,F3:L3),100)
```

DictFromRanges() seems to work fine when I single step it in the debugger.

MinTurnsToKill() is the one that is causing my brainwrong - clearly it's empty, but it's not even getting called (I had code in it originally, but I took it all out just to confirm whether it was getting called).

To further test what was going on I wrote 2 proxy functions:

```
Public Function Proxy(rKeys As Range, rValues As Range) As Variant

    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = DictFromRanges(rKeys, rValues)

    Proxy = MinTurnsToKill(dict, 42)

End Function

Public Function ProxyToo(rKeys As Range, rValues As Range) As Variant

    ProxyToo = MinTurnsToKill(DictFromRanges(rKeys, rValues), 42)

End Function
```

When called as follows from cells in the excel spreadsheet, these both work fine (i.e. both print 42):

```
=Proxy(F2:L2,F4:L4)
=ProxyToo(F2:L2,F4:L4)
```

So, it looks like excel is just refusing to pass the returned dictionary from DictFromRanges() into MinTurnsToKill() if they're used in the evaluation engine that sits inside the actual cells of the spreadsheet.

In fact it's almost as if it is refusing to acknowledge that MinTurnsToKill() even exists when I do the following in a spreadsheet cell:

```
=MinTurnsToKill(DictFromRanges(F2:L2,F3:L3),100)
```

I assume there must be a way to make excel play nicely and I would very much appreciate it if anyone could tell me how :)

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that you use both functions as User Defined Functions (UDFs), i.e. call them from the cells directly. Excel cannot handle a return of the type `Scripting.Dictionary` - and therefore also does not pass this result to your `MinTurnsToKill` function.

Luckily though, Excel can handle `Variant` - and as `Scripting.Dictionary` is "derived" from `Variant` the whole thing will work if you simply change those two lines:

```
Public Function DictFromRanges(...) As Variant
Public Function MinTurnsToKill(dictAttack As Variant, ...
```

Hope that solves your problem.

On a side note: without seeing the real code for you `MinTurnsToKill`, it looks very much like an `HLOOKUP` (or `INDEX`/`MATCH` to me. Maybe there's no need for VBA here at all? Or instead of using the dictionary, you can use `.WorksheetFunction.Hlookup(100, [F2:L3],2,0)`?!

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for thanks Peter :)

You're more than likely right about being able to use HLOOKUP or INDEX / MATCH - my background is C++ and gamedev with some experience of windows programming circa 1998 so my first instinct is to treat excel like a glorified UI control and do everything manually :)

Comment: Further to the above sage advice, I have now re-done the VB code without dictionaries using a mixture of HLOOKUP()/VLOOKUP() and MATCH(). Not needed Index() in VBA code, but was mega useful in just regular formulas. Thanks again Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that Excel expect each function to return 'value' (which is fundamental) while your DictFromRanges returns object. You right, in VBA environment your solution works fine but it breaks the function rules when passed to Excel. 
Suggestion is quite simple- combine both functions into one which will return value.

Comment: So, in essence what you're saying is that there's literally no way to make this work without writing an additional proxy function like Proxy() or ProxyToo() - see above in question - for every case where I might want to pass objects amongst functions?

That is shockingly poor. Minus 10 million points to whoever wrote the interface between excel and VBA.